# Oracle SQL Developer DDL working on more than one schema at once

Tags: database, schema, oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl

I am new to Oracle SQL Developer (about 1 month of use), having always used Toad.  I have 2 almost identical schema set up - one to test older code, one to develop a modified versions. I have 2 different connections set up - one to each schema, with separate user names for each one.

But when I delete a table or column from the schema in one connection, it is also deleted or changed in the other.

This happens if I right-click on the table or field in the Connection explorer panel, or if I open a SQL Script saved to disk. If I open a SQL script, I even see a pop-up that asks me what connection to use, but if I select one, it still makes changes to both.  Even if I only have one of the two connections open, the script will still change design in both of the connections.

The only way I can be sure to make changes to just one of the two is to right-click on the connection name in the Explorer panel, and open a new SQL Worksheet. The worksheet is then named for the connection and just makes changes to it.

This is not the behavior I was expecting, and I'm facing many hours of work to get the definitions of the 2 schema back to where I need them to be.  I am wondering if there is some key concept or distinction I am missing or if there is some way the database(s) are set up that is enabling this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

In case you never found the answer for your question.  This is my understanding:
The database may have several schemas.  The schema is not a separate database, it is a grouping of objects in that database.  If you change something while in one schema, you are really changing it in the database, not just the schema.  I hope this helps.

Are you just trying to test things in one schema?  It sounds like you may want to have a Database and a TEST Database.  You could test whatever you wanted in the TEST database and never have it change the real database.